# Bash Completion for Paths and Nothing Else

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How can I disable bash completion for everything except filesystem paths?

But even for paths, I don't want anything interpreted.

For example, if I do:

`# sh -f fo<tab>`

and there's a file foo.txt, it doesn't work whereas if the file were foo.sh it would. I assume bash is trying to "help" me here. I've been using Linux for a long time and I don't want bash completion to do anything that assumes to know what I'm thinking. I don't want it to look into zip files or guess hostnames. I just want plain path name completion and nothing else.

Comment: I think that's loaded in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Can you check if that is the case in your distribution?

Comment: I think you have this backward.  *Any* tab completion is assuming it knows what you're thinking.  Are you really saying you don't want tab completion for *commands*?

Comment: Can you settle these contradictory phrases? "even for paths, I don't want anything interpreted" and "I just want plain path name completion"

Comment: I suppose I do want command autocomplete. But if the default Fedora 24 profile configures complete to basically hide a file based on suffix, my faith in that component is lost. I want a "minimal" complete profile.

Comment: Completing something from a list is fine. But hiding a file based on suffix is too much interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` has a builtin command `complete` which controls the autocomplete behavior of the current shell. It is possible that your distribution or sysadmin arranged to configure interactive shells by putting these `complete` commands into the configured startup files (traditionally `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/bash_profile`, `~/bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`).

To permanently disable this feature, you can edit these files not to call these `complete` commands (or to call just the ones that you like).

To disable "intelligent" autocomplete just for one instance of interactive session, run

```
complete -r
```

in that session.

Comment: Ok, so `complete -r` does the trick. I suppose I can just set this in `~/.bash_profile`? Am I loosing anything important by clearing everything like this. Path and command tab completion seems to work fine. I'm using Fedora at the moment (normally I use CentOS but this machine is new so I have to use one of the bleeding edge distros) which has all of the complete stuff in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

Comment: @squarewav: I can't guess what is important for you; you can check yourself by `complete -p` to show what you would lose. As to `complete -r` in `~/bash_profile`: it should do the trick, although it would not save you the time that the `bash_completion` script could consume during shell startup (it is noticable on my hardware); I would prefer editing the system-wide configuration instead if that's where `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` gets sourced.